# How to grab string between square brackets and exclude if it is only a number

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will capture string between the square brackets, and if there is a number like (1234) then that should be excluded

I am using the regex

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Suppose the sample data is

```
requests[45180], indices[movies]
```

In this case, I get the output as :

```
[45180]
[movies]
```

But my expected output is :

```
movies
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatcher {
    private static String REGEX = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
    private static String NUMBERS_REGEX = "\\d+";
    private static List sampleData = Arrays.asList("test from [a.b.v1.2.0.71-0] to [a.b.v1.2.0.73-0]",
            "requests[45180], indices[movies]");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile(NUMBERS_REGEX);
        for (Object data : sampleData) {
            List<String> indices = new ArrayList<>();
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data.toString());

            while (matcher.find()) {
                String index = matcher.group().replaceAll("[\\[\\]']+", "");
                Matcher numberMatcher = numberPattern.matcher(index);
                if (!numberMatcher.matches())
                    indices.add(index);
                
            }
            if (indices.size() > 0)
                System.out.println("Indices: " + indices);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: ```"\\[(\\D+)\\]"```  maybe?

Comment: You may add more restrictions to the negative lookahead, `\[(?!(?:\d+|_doc)])([^\]\[]*)]` or `\[(?!\d+])(?!_doc])([^\]\[]*)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of

```
\[([^\]\[]*[^\d\[\]][^\]\[]*)]
\[(?!\d+])([^\]\[]*)]
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/qIiLIH/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/qIiLIH/4).

In Java, you will need to double escape the backslashes in the string literals:

```java
private static String REGEX = "\\[[^\\]\\[]*[^\\d\\[\\]][^\\]\\[]*]";
private static String REGEX = "\\[(?!\\d+])[^\\]\\[]*]";
```

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `[^\d\[\]]` - a char other than `[`, `]` and a digit
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

And

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?!\d+])` - immediately to the right, there cannot be one or more digits followed with a `]` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

In your Java code, you probably can reduce the matching part with

```java
while (matcher.find()) {
    String index = matcher.group(1);
    indices.add(index);
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/3lt8Bo).

Comment: @ESCoder Just add this restriction to the negative lookahead, `\[(?!(?:\d+|_doc)])([^\]\[]*)]`

Comment: may I know the reason of using **group(1)** ?

Comment: @ESCoder The 1 argument extracts the value captured into Group 1. Then there is no need to extract digit sequences with another regex.

Answer (score 2):

If your expected output is "movies", and you don't want to match digits in between the square brackets and not match empty strings, you can use a capture group:

```
\[([^\]\[\d]+)]
```

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\]\[\d]+` match 1+ chars other than `[` `]` or a digit
- `)` Close group 1
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8rwo2E/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/4reBeE)

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\[([^\\]\\[\\d]*)\\]";
```

Example

```
String regex = "\\[([^\\]\\[\\d]+)]";
String string = "requests[45180], indices[movies]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
movies
```